# How to quickly revert data changes in SQL Server database made by an end-to-end test?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, automated-tests, database-restore

Provided we have a suite of end-to-end automated tests, the goal is that every test starts with the same (initial) set of data in the database, to get reliable results.

Has somebody found any good solution how to quickly revert changes that were made in the SQL Server database during test execution?

There is always the possibility to truncate all the tables and re-import the initial data through SQL. But I'm thinking if there is something more elegant. Such as reverting to a snapshot.

Has somebody tried the

```
RESTORE DATABASE FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT
```

SQL Server feature? Is it fast enough? Does the speed of it depend on the amount of data there is in the database when the snapshot is created or does the speed depend rather on how many changes have been made since creation of the snapshot?

Thank you very much for any opinion around this.

Comment: I ended up using the [Respawn library](https://jimmybogard.com/tag/respawn/) - created by Jimmy Bogard of AutoMapper fame - to handle this scenario - check it out! See [How Respawn works](https://jimmybogard.com/how-respawn-works/) for an in-depth explanation

Answer (score 1):

The snapshot feature works by "capturing" the original database pages to the snapshot before they are first modified. It's a kind of copy-on-write. The original page goes to the snapshot, then the modification proceeds normally.

When you revert a snapshot those changed pages are written back to the source database. So the time it takes is proportional to how much data you have changed. Actually it is how much database pages have been changed. Say you changed 100 records but they happened to be on different pages, that's 100 pages to restore. So data locality matters.

Also, since you are making a copy of changed pages before writing to them, it's expected your modifications to take a bit longer.

In my experience it's fast enough, but depends on how much data you are churning.

I wouldn't probably to a truncate/import as I find it to be much more work. If you change a lot of data during your tests restoring a full backup might be easier/faster. You have to check out what works best for you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. That sounds promising, it's definitely worth experimenting and trying out these approaches to find out what works best, as you mentioned. I suppose reverting the db through the full backup restoration may take much more time if the initial set of data in the database is quite huge..

Comment: How long is too long?  If this is a daily refresh requirement and you can refresh overnight, the restoring from a backup would be fast enough.  If you need to refresh more often - then reverting a database snapshot might be fast enough.

The real question then is how often do you need to refresh the data, how large is the database and how much data is being changed during each test.

If there are only a few tables that are changed for each test - it may even be faster to refresh just those tables, but again - that all depends on how large and what 'fast' enough actually means.